# Using functions from inside a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

i wrote a little jQuery button plugin - it contains a method for applying the onclick-function - here's the code

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.tButton = function () 
  {
    this.setFN = function(fn)
    {
        alert("function set.");
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

i'm using this code to initialize it (on a div):

`var button = $("#myButton").tButton();`

now the problem: when trying to apply the setFN function:

```
button.setFN(function(){dosomething();});
```

i'm getting an error: `button.setFN is not a function`

i already tried this.bind instead but didn't help.
anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning anything from the tButton function so the value of tButton isn't what you think  it is.   Try returning `this` from tButton() so to get the jQuery object back out of it.  Also, I don't think this is a good way to do it as you are basically extending jQuery in a non-standard way.  A better way would be to have tButton take the callback function as an argument and apply it to just the matching elements.  I would also use a different pattern for defining the plugin (similar to the UI plugins).

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.extend( {
      tButton: function(callback) {
          return this.each( function() {
             new $.TButton(this,callback);
          });
      }
  });

  $.TButton = function(elem,callback) {
       $(elem).click(callback);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i tried adding return this to at the end of the tButton function - same error.
i think you're right about jquery standards, but i need to be able assigning/changing the button function afterwards.

Comment: Then have the function take multiple arguments and do different things based on those arguments.  If, for instance, the argument list is the string 'click' and a function, reapply the click function to the element, otherwise do the normal thing.

Comment: thanks for your example - looks plain and simple :)
there's only one problem - it won't debug in firebug .. dunno if it's my system.

Comment: `.extend` is unnecessary. `$.fn.tButton = function...` works fine as well.

Comment: Only because I'm only adding a single method.  I use the same pattern regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The function is tButton. If should read like this:

```
var button = $("#myButton").tButton(function(){dosomething();});
```

Comment: where does setFN involve? .. :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pattern you can use do this:

```
$.TButton = function(el){
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.data('TButton', this); // Store a reference to the TButton object on the DOM element
    // Use this.functionName to make it "public"
    this.setFN = function(callback){
       // Namespace the click events so you don't accidently remove
       // other click events bound to the button.
       $el.unbind('click.tbutton').bind('click.tbutton', callback );
    }
}

$.fn.tButton = function(func){
   return this.each(function(){ // Don't break the chain
      if(! func){ // If no parameter is passed, this is a constructor
        (new $.TButton(this));
      } else { // If the parameter (expected to be a function), call setFN
         var button = $(this).data('TButton');
         if(button) button.setFN(func);
      }
   });          
}
```

Now you can initialize using this:

```
$("button").tButton();
```

And can call `setFN` two ways like this:

```
$("button").tButton(function(){ ... });
// or
$("button").data('TButton').setFN( function(){ ... } );
```